# How to onclick RadioButtonList will show/hide a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_donorType" runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem Text="Individual" Value="Individual" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Coporate" Value="Coporate" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" style="visibility:hidden;" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

How to make when I click on List Item `Text="Individual"`, TextBox1 would be visible and when I click on List Item `Text="Coporate"`, TextBox1 would be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_donorType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_donorType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Individual" Value="Individual">
   </asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Coporate" Value="Coporate" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
   test
</asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void rbl_donorType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = rbl_donorType.SelectedItem;

        TextBox1.Visible = selectedItem.Text == "Coporate";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `client side` scripting, which won't need a postback to the server.
Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':radio').click(function(){
            if($(this).val().trim() == "Individual"){
                $(':text').css('visibility','visible');
            }else{
                $(':text').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```